# Managing Chrome memory usage with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I have an 4GB Raspberry Pi doing unit running a Selenium webscraper. Over the course of hours, Chrome's memory footprint eats up all the available memory and the entire bot crashes as a result. Is there a way for Selenium to automatically manage/reduce Chrome's memory usage? I've noticed that if I refresh the page, the memory heep is cleared.

Comment: could you just simply refresh the page by the driver? You can check the ram useage with `psutil`. e.g. `print('RAM memory % used:', psutil.virtual_memory()[2])` source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-current-cpu-and-ram-usage-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

If refreshing the page seems to work, you can just use the following code in a loop that runs every so often.

```
driver.navigate().refresh();
```